# Suspending arithmetic operation in lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

If one types `(+ 2 3)`, lisp returns `5` but how could one tell lisp compiler to return it unevaluated(returning `(+ 2 3)`) ? Is there some flag that could turn off automatic application of operator on operands ? in `read-eval-print`, eval should be suspended.
Since this has to be done as a function that takes in expression and returns it unevaluated, how do I quote it inside function ?

Comment: You know about `(quote (+ 2 3))`  or shorter: `'(+ 2 3)`, do you?

Comment: @Dirk: I mean to say `(defun qt(expr)(quote expr))` then for `(qt (+ 2 3))` it should return `(+ 2 3)` not `expr`.

Comment: See my answer below. But consider adding a little bit more context. What is it, that you want to achieve?

Comment: @Dirk: I want to hold an expression and prevent it from any evaluation. Like that in Mathematica,http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hold.html

Comment: Hm. Mathematica has a totally different concept of evaluation than common lisp has (term rewriting). I am not sure, whether what you are trying to achieve is in any way meaningful...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For common lisp, there is no way receive the "quoted" original expression as argument to a plain function. [The evaluation rules are fixed](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_ababc.htm). You can do, what you want, with a macro, however

```
(defmacro my-quote (expr) (list 'quote expr))
==> MY-QUOTE

(my-quote (+ 2 3))
==> (+ 2 3)
```

Answer (score 2):

FWIW in Racket (I know it isn't Common Lisp) an application like (+ 2 3) is expanded to (#%app + 2 3). If you rebind #%app to your own macro, you can change the result of evaluating (+ 2 3).

A complete example:

```
#lang racket

(module my-app racket
  (define-syntax (my-app stx)
    (syntax-case stx ()
      [(my-app procedure argument ...)
       #''(procedure argument ...)]))
  (provide (rename-out [my-app #%app])))

(require (submod "." my-app))

(+ 2 x)
```

The result of running this program is `'(+ 2 x)`